# Android Studio Cant change from Advance attribute view to basic Attribute View

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a problem where I can't change my attribute view to basic attribute view (which is lot of features on the common attribute section). This is my current attribute pane. I tried to restore the default setting but nothing happens.

here's my view:
[image: my view]

This is the example of basic view/ common attribute that I want to access:
[image: what I looking for]

Comment: Hi Orochi, do you see the header "All Attributes" (to the right / upper corner of your screenshot)?

Comment: No. I still not find them